# Value of a limit inside another limit

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Suppose $L=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)$, where $L$ is finite. Can I calculate $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{L-f(x)}{L-g(x)}$$ without knowing either $f'(x)$ or $g'(x)$?

Comment: Would $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x^2$, $L=0$ constitute a counterexample?

Comment: @SK19 And then reverse the roles of $f$ and $g$...

Comment: @SK19 there is also the condition $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)/g(x)=1$ but it doesn't change so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No we can't since we don't know the rate for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to tend at L (that is just the information we can have by derivatives).

Let for example

- $f(x)=x+L$
- $g(x)=x^2+L$

or

- $f(x)=x^2+L$
- $g(x)=x+L$

Comment: I forgot to include that we know that $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)/g(x)=1$. Does it make a difference?

Comment: It is implicitely assumed in $L=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)$ and 
the examples you see are indeed such that $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)/g(x)=1$.